# Why is my hosts file not working?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-vista, hosts-file

I've been using the hosts file to for local website development, and it's recently stopped working. No entries other than localhost resolve.

I've simplified to test, so it now contains only

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1        localhost
127.0.0.1  test.dev
```

localhost responds to ping, test.dev does not.

- The file is called `hosts` with no extension
- It has no trailing spaces
- It's saved in C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc which matches the value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\DataBasePath
- Oddly, despite UAC being on, I can edit, delete and save the file without admin permissions
- No proxy is being used, PC is not connected to network for testing
- Stopping the DNS Client service seemed to resolve the issue for a few minutes, test.dev briefly resolved but doesn't any more.
- Only firewall is Windows'
- Machine has been restarted.

Is there anything else I should try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tried everything suggested here, I resolved the issue by reinstalling Windows.

Comment: Damn, those rare *very* cases where nuking is the only solution for rather stupid reasons :S

Answer (score 3):

Avoid multiple entires for the same IP — write multiple hostnames on the same line (with the first being the canonical name). e.g.:

`127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain test.dev`

`::1 localhost localhost.localdomain test.dev`

If you’re still having problems, try (from a command prompt):

`net stop dnscache`

Comment: The first part of this does seem to have worked! Many thanks.

Comment: Hmm, without any further changes to hosts, test.dev again does not resolve. The DNS Client service is disabled. Seems there's another issue here.

Comment: when you say “does not resolve” do you mean a `ping test.dev` from the command-line fails, or are you testing a different way?

(Also, might be worth removing the `test.dev` from the `::1` line — if you're not properly set up for IPv6, it might confuse matters having it there).

Comment: `ping test.dev` from command line now fails, with or without `::1 test.dev`

Comment: okay, something else is going on somewhere, though I must confess I’m not sure what it might be — your hosts file is present (and correct as far as I can assume), the DNS caching service isn’t getting in the way to confuse matters. I’m a bit stumped.

Comment: Thankyou for all your advice on this, but I'm now thinking it's time to reformat and reinstall Windows, rather than spend any more time on the specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried either removing the line:

```
::1        localhost
```

or adding the line:

```
::1        test.dev
```

**Update**

There used to be issues in the past if the hosts file contained spaces rather than tabs between the address and the name. I haven't checked recently enough to know whether that's still the case. You could try making sure that the delimiter is a tab rather than spaces.

Comment: Yes and yes, with no effect, but isn't that entry for IPv6 compatibility?

Comment: @elliot100 - I think so, I was just trying to suggest that you make the version that doesn't work identical to the version that does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`#  127.0.0.1   localhost

   ::1         localhost

   ::1         test.dev
   127.0.0.1   test.dev`

Comment: Still does not resolve test.dev...

Answer (score 0):

**I was able to solve my problem by not using .dev as my TLD** (Top Level Domain).

Apparently Google owns .dev, and has set up HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) to ensure that all requests to any .dev site automatically redirect to https :(.  I believe this is implemented in the browsers, and happened for me in both Chrome and Safari.

**Solution: Use .test(or any other TLD) instead of .dev**

Here's a link with more information about this topic: https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Comment: See RFC 2606 and RFC 6761 before using any TLD.